# query ember-data store not cached when using query

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the /photos route of my ember-app I can see that if I use the query function, the records does not come from local indexedDB:

the route has a loading template with a spinner;

if in the route I do:

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('photo');
}
```

the record are loaded only the first time; I see the spinner for a while and then the photo are shown; if I go on another route and then back to the photos route, the spinner is not shown, the data are taken from local indexedDB and a new request to the REST api is done in background;

but if I do

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.query('photo', {}});
}
```

I see the spinner not only the first time but every time I open the route;
so I guess the data is fetched again

Comment: that is correct behaviour, because ember data cannot know if same query request return same set objects all the time so cannot cache it

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out...  Is there any way to work around this to tell ember data to behave like findall? (caching and making new request in background?)

Comment: I don't think it is possible you can build your own caching mechanism on top of ember-data query I think

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, `ember-data`s intention is to make sure the data thats consumed is as in sync with the server as possible.. thus calling `findAll` it will return you new data to make sure it hasnt changed.  You can on the other hand employ methods such as `findRecord`, `peekRecord` and `peekAll` to have more control if 
you want this data from the cache or freshly loaded

---

`peekRecord` will load the data exclusively from the cache for one model.
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekRecord

---

If you want the content to be loaded from the cache you want to use `findRecord`.  If not loaded it will make a request, then subsequent requests will come from the cache.

`store.findRecord('filter', 1)`
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord

I also recommend you use the ember inspector browser extension to see what models are loaded in the cache for more clarity.

---

If you want to see all the currently loaded content for a model you may use `peekAll`
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekAll

Comment: but findRecord returns a single record; is there an equivalent to return an array of records?

Comment: @CerealKiller yes sir.  Updated the answer with `peekAll`